# Why does not RStudio shiny app start up from index.html correctly?

Tags: html, user-interface, rstudio, bootstrapping, shiny

I had a working shiny app. I saved the HTML it generated in the www directory as index.html and removed ui.R. According to http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html this is all I have to do in order to startup from index.html instead of creating the UI with the shinyUI() function.

However this way the plots were not rendered.

If I start the application form ui.R and within the same session I remove ui.R and start from index.html, it works. If I edit some text in index.html, it will appear edited, so I'm sure it boots form index.html.

However if I close RStudio, start it again and make a fresh run from index.html, the plots won't render.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to copy all the `.js` dependencies of the application to its `www` folder ( in the same directory where the `index.html` is ). You can find out the dependencies by studying the `<head>` section of the generated `html` and find the actual `.js` files in the library directories.

For example to be able to use plotly charts you have to copy `plotly.js` from `plotly/htmlwidgets` and `plotly-latest.min.js` from `plotly/htmlwidgets/lib/plotlyjs`.

Also in the `<head>` section you have to remove any prefix in the name of the same dependencies so that they now point to the `www` directory. For example instead of `plotly-binding-2.0.16/plotly.js` just use `plotly.js`.

To get everything right is far from trivial.